# Couldn't find executable named microstrain_mips_node

Tags: ros, c++, gps

I installed ROS `microstrain_mips` using `git clone` in my workspace. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/microstrain_3dm_gx5_45) is the Wiki page of the package. However, my current ROS version is Noetic, and the package supports Indigo. When I try to execute the launch file after installation, I encounter an error saying, `Couldn't find executable named microstrain_mips_node.`

1. I'm curious if ROS `microstrain_mips` is compatible with Noetic.
2. If `microstrain_mips_node` isn't running as it should, I'm wondering how to resolve this issue.

I've already executed `catkin_make` and `source ./devel/setup.bash` before running `roslaunch`.

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. When I clone the package into the existed WS, the package is not installed in ./devel/lib folder, so I did't get any output of: find . -name microstrain_mips_node. However, when i clone the package into a new workspace, it worked in it. In the existed WS, there are a couple of python ROS packages. Do you think it is the problem?

Comment: Did you carefully check the catkin_make output for errors? When you build from src, you are required to install all dependencies that the ros package needs.

Comment: Hi, Mike. I checked the catkin_make output but I did not get any error message.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the output of: `find . -name microstrain_mips_node` and run this from your catkin_ws directory.

Comment: Also tell us what operating system and version you are using.

Comment: I run the find command line but I did not receive any output, and then checked ./devel/lib but there is not the package name in the lib directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

I could successfully install [microstrain_mips](https://github.com/ros-drivers/microstrain_mips) package on ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Below are the steps, I followed:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/microstrain_ws/src/
$ cd ~/microstrain_ws/src/
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/microstrain_mips.git
$ rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src -r -y
$ cd cd ~/microstrain_ws/
$ source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
$ catkin_make
```

Next, I was able to run the node. It showed some obvious error as I don't have the device connected. However, until here, it seems to be working well.

```
$ source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
$ source devel/setup.bash 
$ roscore
$ rosrun microstrain_mips microstrain_mips_node
[ INFO] [1699613921.567464487]: Attempting to open serial port </dev/ttyACM1> at <115200> 

Unable to open com Port /dev/ttyACM1
 Errno = 2
[FATAL] [1699613921.568017008]: Couldn't open serial port!  Is it plugged in?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can also run `microstrain.launch` as shown below:

```
$ roslaunch microstrain_mips microstrain.launch
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/893a16fc-7fb9-11ee-a910-db79fbf4f264/roslaunch-dell-5876.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://dell:35581/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/auto_init: True
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/baudrate: 115200
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/declination: 0.23
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/declination_source: 2
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/device_setup: True
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/dynamics_mode: 1
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/frame_based_enu: False
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/gps_frame_id: navsat_link
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/gps_rate: 4
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/imu_angular_cov: [0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0...
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/imu_frame_id: gx5_link
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/imu_linear_cov: [0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0...
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/imu_orientation_cov: [0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0...
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/imu_rate: 100
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/nav_rate: 10
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/odom_child_frame_id: base_link
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/odom_frame_id: wgs84_odom_link
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/port: /dev/microstrain
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/publish_filtered_imu: False
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/publish_imu: True
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/readback_settings: True
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/remove_imu_gravity: True
 * /gx5/microstrain_mips_node/save_settings: True
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/expected: ['microstrain_mip...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/imu/expected: ['microstrain_mip...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/imu/path: imu
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/imu/remove_prefix: microstrain_mips_...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/imu/timeout: 5.0
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/imu/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/packet/expected: ['microstrain_mip...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/packet/path: packet
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/packet/remove_prefix: microstrain_mips_...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/packet/timeout: 5.0
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/packet/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/path: general
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/port/expected: ['microstrain_mip...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/port/path: port
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/port/remove_prefix: microstrain_mips_...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/port/timeout: 5.0
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/port/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/remove_prefix: microstrain_mips_...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/timeout: 5.0
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/analyzers/general/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/path: microstrain_mips_...
 * /imu_diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/microstrain_mips_node/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0

NODES
  /
    imu_diagnostic_aggregator (diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node)
  /gx5/
    microstrain_mips_node (microstrain_mips/microstrain_mips_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5884]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 893a16fc-7fb9-11ee-a910-db79fbf4f264
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5894]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gx5/microstrain_mips_node-2]: started with pid [5901]
process[imu_diagnostic_aggregator-3]: started with pid [5902]
[ INFO] [1699614534.743373413]: Attempting to open serial port </dev/microstrain> at <115200> 

Unable to open com Port /dev/microstrain
 Errno = 2
[FATAL] [1699614534.743634974]: Couldn't open serial port!  Is it plugged in?
[gx5/microstrain_mips_node-2] process has died [pid 5901, exit code -11, cmd /home/user/microstrain_ws/devel/lib/microstrain_mips/microstrain_mips_node __name:=microstrain_mips_node __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/893a16fc-7fb9-11ee-a910-db79fbf4f264/gx5-microstrain_mips_node-2.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/893a16fc-7fb9-11ee-a910-db79fbf4f264/gx5-microstrain_mips_node-2*.log
^C[imu_diagnostic_aggregator-3] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, ravi. I really appreciate for your help! I have tried to clone the package into the existed work space, but it was not worked. However, now, it is working in the new ws. Thank you so much for your help again!

Comment: If you add a new package to your `catkin_ws/src` directory, or you modify an existing CMakeLists.txt file, it is generally a good idea to rebuild everything (do a "clean build".) For catkin_make, you do this by deleting the top-level `devel` and `build` directories in the `catkin_ws` directory, then running `catkin_make` again.

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry for the late response.  It is working on my computer. I really appreciate for your help again. Have a great day!